# jqGridPHP : jqGridRender Class > setColProperty > "editoptions"=>array("value"=> $datetime) > How to format the $datetime php variable?

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

In a php file, i use the jqGridRender Class to build and manage a grid.

To add a new item in my SQL table, i use (among others things) a php variable named `$start`. This variable is known, it belong to the PRIMARY KEY of this new item i want to add. Its type in the table is DATETIME and its value is "2010-06-16 06:00:00"

- How to format `$start` variable in the followsing line ?

  ```
  $grid->setColProperty("start", array("hidden"=>true,"editoptions"=>array("value"=> $start),"editrules"=>array("required"=>true)));
  ```

In fact, when i use it as the above line,`$start`equals "2010-06-16 06:00:00" becomes "2021-12-01 06:00:00" in the table.

What to do, please ?

Regards, Qualliarys

Answer (score 2):

Here is the response !

I just need to add this following line code :

```
 // Set a new user datetime format using PHP convensions
 $grid->setUserTime('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```